# How to close an open anchor tag which queries a mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a site which includes PHP queries from another programmer. I am in the process of validating the page html and have discovered a php generated 'a href' tag which is not closed giving an error.

```
$link= "<a href=\"modules.php?x=".$row['ID']."\">".$completed_modules." Modules".(($completed_modules >= 8) ? ' (Completed)' : '');
```

I have tried placing closing 'anchor tag' in numerous places but without success e.g:

```
    $link= "<a href=\"modules.php?x=".$row['ID']."\">".$completed_modules." Modules".(($completed_modules >= 8) ? ' (Completed)' : '')\"</a>\"; //does not work
```

Does anyone know how to close the anchor please?

Comment: Try this...
$link= "<a href=\"modules.php?x=".$row['ID']."\">".$completed_modules." Modules".(($completed_modules >= 8) ? ' (Completed)' : '') . "</a>";

Comment: Thanks for your help worked fine

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php
  $link= "<a href=\"modules.php?x=".$row['ID']."\">".$completed_modules." Modules".(($completed_modules >= 8) ? ' (Completed)' : '')."</a>"; 
  echo $link;
?>
```